# Hosting multiple React apps with one S3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, deployment

I use S3 static website hosting for React apps in my dev and prod environments and it works great. I use a bucket naming scheme like `dev-myapp-mycompany` and `prod-myapp-mycompany` and have a dedicated bucket for each environment.

My team constantly creates feature branches that need testing and while I could create a new bucket for each new branch, we would have to ask for a bucket increase within a few sprints and then prune them frequently.

What I'd like to do is have a single bucket `feature-myapp-mycompany` with a simple `index.html` at the root which would provide a link to each app currently deployed into this feature bucket. Something like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Feature Bucket</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Feature Branches</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="./feature1/index.html">Feature 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./feature2/index.html">Feature 2</a>
        </li>
        ...
        <li>
            <a href="./featuren/index.html">Feature n</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

For this the bucket structure would look like

```
index.html
    /feature1
        index.html
        /static
    /feature2
        index.html
        /static
    /featuren
        index.html
        /static
```

I deploy all of the apps through the AWS cli, so it isn't a challenge to script it. I use something like

1. `npm run build`
2. `aws s3 sync ./build s3://%bucket%/%feature% --delete --profile=%profile% --region=us-east-1`

Getting the code out to the buckets is no problem. Here is where I get stuck:

**My Problem:**
I have the code deployed as described above but the create-react-app project defines its static dependencies from the root of the domain. So the index.html for feature1 has hrefs like `/static/css/main.9fac6334.chunk.css`. This request goes and looks at the root of my bucket where there is only the primary `index.html` and a "directory" for each feature. My links on the main `index.html` do indeed take me to the right app `index.html` but none of the script or css references are valid since they are based on the root.

**Attempted Solution:**
create-react-app allows you to specify a `homepage` option in the `package.json` that is uses to set the baseURL in your app. What I seem to need is relative paths, not absolute ones, so I tried to set the value of homepage to `"./"` and then `http://feature-myapp-mycompany.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/feature1`. In both cases, the links take me to the right place for a moment and then redirect me back to the main `index.html` file at the root. I know it's kind of working because I see the styling and theme of my site for a split-second before it redirects me. I even see the right requests happening in the network tab of Chrome, but after all the requests are attempted, I see it redirect back to the primary index document at the root.

**Attempted Solution Continued:**
S3 static hosting allows redirection rules. I attempted a variety of redirect options that ended up putting me in an infinite loop for the same resource which caused the request to fail. My configuration was something like

```
 <RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>feature1/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>feature1/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
  </RoutingRules>
```

Of course, this didn't work because it was rewriting the prefix back to the same value. Doing the same kind of redirect rules without my Attempted Solution also did not work since the request was not going to a resource with prefix `feature1/`, it was going to the root.

**My ideal solution:**
I'd like to have some combination of the `homepage` option in the `package.json` and some redirect rules in place to redirect requests for static resources within each app back to the root of their respective feature branch directories. For example a request for the `/static/css/main.9fac6334.chunk.css` should look inside the `feature1` directory, not the root.

I'm not afraid of scripting this for the many branches we will have but I can't seem to get the options right for an individual example sub-app.

Thank you in advance for helping out and best of luck in your own coding adventures.

Comment: You should have a look at Amplify Console which does, among other things, feature branch deployments https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/console/

Comment: thank you. I was able to set this up quickly but got a little frustrated by how new and immature the tooling was with the cli. Rather than use root credentials, my company does everything through roles and the cli profile you associate does not honor profiles that use a role. On the console, though,I gpt set up in a matter of minutes. Thank you for pointing out this service so I could be sure it was possible. I'm pretty sure amplify just wraps the bucket and cloudfront creation for you which is nice but unnecessary for me for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to use [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314452/how-can-my-s3-bucket-host-multiple-websites-in-different-folders-using-nginx/41317237#41317237) to accomplish what I needed to do. We already were using a cloudfront distribution for our other environments and this was very easy to set up.

Here's a summary of what we learned here:

1. It is definitely possible to host multiple react apps in the same bucket
2. You can put each app into a directory/prefix of your choosing
3. Create a cloudfront distribution for each app pointing to your bucket with settings like the following

   a. Put feature1 in bucket directory/prefix `feature1/`

   b. Create a distribution with Origin Path `/feature1` and Default root object `index.html`

   c. Ride away clean

Comment: Can you also do it without the CloudFront distribution?

Comment: The answer appears to be no. You can only have one root object and essentially this is setting up multiple.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I'll see what I can do then!

Comment: to clarify: you effectively create a CF distribution for each feature branch and when you're done with it you delete the distribution?

Comment: That's right. It's one bucket with as many distributions as you have features. The distribution allows you to set the root object which is your index.html for each feature app. You could use the same concept to host multiple unrelated apps as well. You will need to delete them after a while to stay under your quota. If you name the distributions consistently, you can use a webhook on a git branch delete to disable and remove the CD distribution.

Comment: Additional question; how are you mapping the additional cloudfront distributions onto the same domains?

IE: in your example:
 - foo.com/feature1 (cloudfront distribution - 1)
 - foo.com/feature2 (cloudfront distribution - 2)

or were you using all subdomains to achieve this?

@rictionaryFever

Comment: in my case, I'm using the generated cf distribution domain provided. In this feature branch setup, whenever a branch is built, the index.html at the root of the bucket is regenerated with the existing branches and links to them. A dev or BA looking for a branch just goes to the one dev site that lists the available feature branches and then finds the link with the relevant branch name.

Comment: got it; appreciate the followup. I ended up with a lambda method after working a handful of different ways. My use case is slightly different where I want to be catching the 404/403 at bucket levels based on behaviors, sadly CF has that at the root context vs behavior context.  Cheers!

Comment: how can I do with a single cloud front? I am not getting any lead to resolve the issue/accomplish my requirement. My requirement is below.
----------

index.html
    /feature1
        index.html
        /static
    /feature2
        index.html
        /static
    /feature3
        index.html
        /static
---------

somedomain.com/feature1
somedomain.com/feature2
somedomain.com/feature3